# how can i store data from jQuery.post to a local variable so that i can work with it?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

```
this.formsValidation = function(form_id)
{
    var fieldNames;
    jQuery.post('index.php','option=com_itcs_forms&controller=itcs_fields&task=getFieldsNameForValidation&tmpl=component&form_id='+form_id,
    function(data)
    {
        fieldNames = data;
    });
    alert(fieldNames);
    return false;
}
```

here "fieldNames" is showing "undefined" although it must show a string which is in "data".
i am unable to store "data" to a variable, so that i can work with it after "post" function. how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: use firebug or other console in chrome or even i ie. Put break point and see what is in the data, data.response is maybe where your data is.

Comment: Your formatting, it hurts my eyes... When asking a question, please do try to format your code so that it is nicely indented and as readable as possible. Help people help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following -

```
this.formsValidation = function(form_id)
{
    var fieldNames;
    jQuery.post('index.php','option=com_itcs_forms&controller=itcs_fields&task=getFieldsNameForValidation&tmpl=component&form_id='+form_id, 
     function(data)
     {
         fieldNames = data;
         alert(fieldNames);
     });

     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment should work, but your code is executing asynchronously - that is, you are issuing your AJAX call, then immediately executing `alert()` before the AJAX call has completed. If you wish to work with the data you should do so in the AJAX callback, thereby guaranteeing you have data when your code executes:

```
var fieldNames;
jQuery.post('index.php','option=com_itcs_forms&controller=itcs_fields&task=getFieldsNameForValidation&tmpl=component&form_id='+form_id,
function(data)
  {
     fieldNames = data;
     alert(fieldNames);
     // do more stuff here

  });
```

Comment: thank you all for assisting, i have got my answer. the problem was with "ajax synchronization. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call   this is the answer